# Apache HttpClient HttpGet url with colon

Tags: java, httpclient, url-encoding, apache-httpclient-4.x

I am trying to issue a get with a colon in one of my parameters but it fails with an `unknownHostException` here is my code:

```
String id = "{\"ID\":\"John Doe\"}";
String encodedID = URLEncoder.encode(id, "UTF-8").replace("+", "%20");
endpoint="https://127.0.0.1/getResourceNameToUse?id=" + encodedID;
HttpResponse response = new HttpResponse();
HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(endpoint);
response = httpclient.execute(httpget, new RESTResponseHandler());
```

I get the following error:

> java.net.UnknownHostException: 127.0.0.1/getResourceNameToUse?id={"ID"

So it would seem that the colon is breaking the get request. Is there a way to fix this? Why is encoding it not fixing the problem? My encoded id looks like this:

```
    
%7B%22ID%22%3A%22John%20Doe%22%7D
```

Comment: I was able to fix it by essentially double url encoding the colon: String id = id.replace(":","%3A");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to fix it by essentially double url encoding the colon:

```
String id = "{\"ID\":\"John Doe\"}";
id = id.replace(":","%3A");
String encodedID = URLEncoder.encode(id, "UTF-8").replace("+", "%20");
endpoint="https://127.0.0.1/getResourceNameToUse?id=" + encodedID;
HttpResponse response = new HttpResponse();
HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(endpoint);
response = httpclient.execute(httpget, new RESTResponseHandler());
```

Answer (score 2):

When I run an approximation of your code, your resulting URL is:

```
https://127.0.0.0/getResourceNameToUse?id=%7B%22ID%22%3A%22John%20Doe%22%7D
```

This is an absolutely valid URL as far as I can see.  I don't see any `:` characters in it that would confuse the `HttpClient`.  Let's look at the exception:

```
java.net.UnknownHostException: 127.0.0.0/getResourceNameToUse?id={"ID"
```

It looks to me that something is *not* using your encoded URL since it shows the `{"ID` as opposed to `%7B%22ID%22`.  Any chance your code in your post isn't *exactly* the code you were running?

I also notice that you are going to the IP `127.0.0.0`.  Any chance you wanted `127.0.0.1` to connect to localhost?

Comment: Sorry, typo on the localhost address. I was actually hitting another address but didn't want to post it. As far as the url goes, as you see it is exactly as I sent it. The httpclient must have been decoding it before I sent it because I had to double url encode the colon.

Comment: Can you post your code snippet to http://pastebin.com/ @ferics2?  I'm really interested to see it.

Comment: I tried the same code and do not get any problems.  That's with HttpClient 3.1 however.  You seem to be using an earlier version.  I can't believe however that it would decode the URL passed into it.  Something else is going on @ferics.

Comment: It could be the version of the client we are using. We are on httpclient-4.1-beta1. I am just glad I was able to get it to work :)